# Emacs TRAMP mode doesn't work (Every file I open is empty)

Tags: emacs, tramp

I used TRAMP mode quite a lot in the last few days. But now it suddenly stopped working. Whenever I attempt to access a remote file, emacs freezes for about a minute and when the file opens, it's always empty.

My emacs version is:
`GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS apple-appkit-1348.17)` 
And my TRAMP mode version is: `2.2.11-24.5`

Comment: You will likely need to provide more info than that. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Additionally to what Drew has said, you might also call `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections`. Tramp keeps connection information in its cache, and some of them even survive an Emacs restart. The command clears all caches.

Comment: Running `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections` worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when using tramp on a Windows 10 environment. I found that files over 4096 bytes were being compressed when transferred from the remote with gzip, which wasn't supported on Windows 10 (I could probably have fixed that).  I fixed this by changing the `tramp-inline-compress-start-size` variable to `nil`.  In my case, this didn't cause a performance issue, but it may be better for you to add gzip to your environment.